# Accessing a Class through ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I am writing a ruby gem that is importing data to ActiveRecord, taking in the environment and Class the user wants to put in the data.
I am able to connect to the environment with ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...), but I can not figure out how to access the passed in Class to do, say, Location.create(...).

I don't want to pass it in via execute, because it'll skip validations, but I'm doubting I can access the ActiveRecord class.

I found an article that I thought would help (http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=212), but with this I am putting:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.const_get(model).create(attributes)
```

and getting

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::Location (NameError)
```

When I try the above with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.const_get(model) I just get a huge object back.  I'm just looking for a way to get to the class like how if I was in Rails I could just call User.create().  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In response to the first two answers, this code is being carried out in a gem not in Rails itself, hence me establishing a connection first.  I am getting "uninitialized constant User (NameError)" for the constantize approach and "uninitialized constant Module::User (NameError)" for the Module approach.  @spickermann

Comment: @Зелёный tagging you too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#constantize`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize) and [`String#classify`](http://apidock.com/rails/Inflector/classify):

```
=> cons = "user".classify.constantize
#> User
=> cons.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call this on `ActiveRecord::Base`, because that model is a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`, but not a constant in the `ActiveRecord::Base` namespace.

Instead just call it on `Module`:

```
Module.const_get(model).create(attributes)
```

Comment: I am still getting the error with this.  To clarify, the code above is within my gem's Module, which is not related to ActiveRecord.  I thought that maybe there was a method to ActiveRecord that would give me the model Class put in.